# “invalid active developer path” when attempting to use pip3 after upgrading to macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, xcode, catalina

I am trying to run `pip3` from Terminal and the following error shows up:

`xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun.`

I have just upgraded my os to Catalina and have already tried:

```
xcode-select --install
```

which shows me:

```
Can't download the software because of a network problem
```

And:

```
sudo xcode-select --reset
```

which outputs nothing and when I run `pip3` again, I get the same error. Is there anything else that could be done? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are perfect in your thinking. The true error is your machine needs a valid, secured web connection back to Apple’s content delivery network and servers. See if you can download any app from the Mac App Store and then when that’s working, retry the install.

```
xcode-select --install
```

Apple generally requires you to allow outbound traffic to the 17.0.0.0 network range, so if you’re on a filtered network, consider using a VPN to get outside the restrictions or have networking open outbound ports for your device to rule that out as an error.

Once you’ve gotten a good install, the select command above will report that the developer tools are installed and to use Software Update to update them. Since you tagged your question Xcode you could install that as well and then run it - it will install the tools as well (including the `xcrun` tool which is the first item needed by `pip3`)

Comment: 10-4, had to ask our IT guy to make this work. Switched to a less restricted network and fixed the issue. Thanks

Comment: b***mike***, you made my day!!! helped me with getting git installed on my mac!! thank you. after running the command, xcode-select --install, and aftewr installation completed, I was able to see that git is installed!!! :) I was getting error: xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcru . whern was running git --version
Now I see it!!!

Comment: This worked on my mac after I upgraded my OS to Ventura.